# Pandas apply to create multiple columns, using multiple columns as input

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a function to create multiple outputs, using multiple columns as inputs. Here's my attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(6, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head()

    A   B   C   D
0   8   2   5   0
1   9   9   8   6
2   4   0   1   7
3   8   4   0   3
4   5   6   9   9

def some_func(a, b, c):
    return a+b, a+b+c

df['dd'], df['ee'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['A'], b = x['B'], c = x['C']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

df.head()

   A    B   C   D   dd  ee
0   8   2   5   0   0   1
1   9   9   8   6   0   1
2   4   0   1   7   0   1
3   8   4   0   3   0   1
4   5   6   9   9   0   1
```

The outputs are all 0 for the first new column, and all 1 for the next new column. I am interested in the correct solution, but I am also curious about why my code resulted this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign to subset `['dd','ee']`:

```
def some_func(a, b, c):
    return a+b, a+b+c

df[['dd','ee']] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['A'], 
                                               b = x['B'], 
                                               c = x['C']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  dd  ee
0  4  7  7  3  11  18
1  2  1  3  4   3   6
2  4  7  6  0  11  17
3  0  9  1  1   9  10
4  5  6  5  9  11  16
5  3  2  4  9   5   9
```

If possible, better/ fatser is use vectorized solution:

```
df = df.assign(dd = df.A + df.B, ee = df.A + df.B + df.C)
```

Comment: can df assign be used for complicated functions? I was using a minimal example, but my function irl involves processing in a library which uses a gpu.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 - It depends of function, mainly if possible processing by arrays. It means if you can add input all values of columns and output is new Series (unfortunately many custom function cannot do it :()

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain the 0, 1 part. 0 and 1 are actually the column names of

```
df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['A'], b = x['B'], c = x['C']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

That is

```
x = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(a = x['A'], b = x['B'], c = x['C']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
a, b = x
print(a)    # first column name
print(b)    # second column name

output:
0
1
```

Finally, you assign

```
df['dd'], df['ee'] = 0, 1
```

results in

```
   A    B   C   D   dd  ee
0   8   2   5   0   0   1
1   9   9   8   6   0   1
2   4   0   1   7   0   1
3   8   4   0   3   0   1
4   5   6   9   9   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
df['dd'], df['ee'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: some_func(x['A'], x['B'], x['C]) )
```